# How to make a round point or a rounder point in this case, where edges come together and join into one vertex?

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges

I would like to ask how to make a round point or rounder point in this case. Sorry I am a complete beginner and tried with the bevel and loop cut tool (loop cut did not work at all), the subdivision surface modifier only worked on the whole object. The object also already has an applied mirror modifier. Thank you so much for answering in case you do.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yoy cannot round 1 vertex.
You need to add more geometry.

Nothing in the real world is perfectly pointy, so use a face, instead of one vertex.
By scaling it you can make it more or less pointy.

[image]

You can use the subdivision modifier to smooth out the whole object.
[image]

Or use bevel to only smooth out the rim.
[image]